Uncaught TypeError: (destructured parameter).profile is null
I'm encountering a TypeError when using map function in TypeScript. I'm mapping over an array of objects and rendering their properties using destructuring syntax. In the object the profile property might be null and I've already handled the JSX syntax just like below:
{`${last_name} ${middle_name} ${first_name}` || ""}

What I have tried. However there is still TypeError this time null has no properties.
              (
                {
                  id,
                  email,
                  role: { role },
                  profile: {
                    first_name,
                    middle_name,
                    last_name,
                    address_details: { address_line_one, address_line_two } = {},
                  } = {},
                  date_joined,
                  is_active,
                }: User = {},
                index
              )

@types/user.d.ts
export interface User {
  id: number;
  email: string;
  role: Role;
  profile: Profile;
  date_joined: string;
  is_active: boolean;
}

interface Role {
  role: string;
}

interface Profile {
  first_name?: string;
  middle_name?: string;
  last_name?: string;
  address_details: AddressDetails;
}

interface AddressDetails {
  address_line_one?: string;
  address_line_two?: string;
}

export type UserList = User[];


Destructuring doesn't use default values for null.
const user = {profile: null}
const {profile = {}} = user

In this case profile will be null, even if you do profile = {} because the default is not used. So if you read anything from profile, you get an error.
You could destructure like so:
const {profile = {}} = user
const {
    first_name,
    middle_name,
    last_name,
    address_details: { address_line_one, address_line_two } = {},
} = profile || {}

The || {} part will handle even a null value.

Tried the suggested solution using || {} but still getting Uncaught TypeError: null has no properties.

We're probably going to need more info. The error likely has a specific line.
